# Silverlight Toolkit Charting Control - Show "Column" Colours

Tags: silverlight, charts, toolkit

In the silverlight toolkit chart control, the legend on the X Axis can show an indeterminate amount of points. E.g. 1,2,3,4,5.

Would it be possible to colour the virtual columns that this creates?  I.e. in the space where legend mark 2 is shown, the space above to the top of the control is shaded to a different colour.  This will make it interesting as as the chart scales, the legends on the X Axis change with the size available.

This is mainly for a series of type ScatterSeries for my specific example but could extend to a series of LineSeries.

Hope this explains my requirements.

Comment: Specify what series type you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really possible due to the fact that there are no virtual columns created.

The chart is a canvas and the scatter point is just a point positioned on it. Your best bet would be to create your own ColumnSeries type and then style it to look like a ScatterSeries with your desired background colour.

Comment: It seems this is so. Even if the visual tree has no concept of a "column" I was hoping the chart would be able to help.  For the moment what I have done is use an AreaSeries to cover the area I want, push this behind my scatter series and everything looks pretty good.